# Accessing Swashbuckle swagger RootUrl/swagger/docs does not provide any output

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swashbuckle

I have a web api 2 project. It is configured to be self hosted using owin. It doesnt have any global.asax file. I need to have help pages for the web api, and have used swaschbuckle for it. But rooturl/swagger/docs is not giving any output.

I have followed the instructions here 'https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/196', but it is still not working. Below is my configuration code

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Configure DI
    container = BuildDI();

    // Create the configuration. OWIN Should create a new httpconfiguration.
    // GlobalConfiguration can't be used.
    HttpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();

    HttpConfiguration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
    HttpConfiguration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    HttpConfiguration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

    // Set ServicePointManager properties.
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);

    // 10 concurrent connections can be made on the service point.
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10;

    // After the idle time expires, the ServicePoint object is eligible for 
    // garbage collection and cannot be used by the ServicePointManager object.
    ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 30000; // 30 Seconds.

    app.UseSerilogRequestContext("RequestId");

    // Middleware is injected form DI.
    app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);

    app.UseAutofacWebApi(HttpConfiguration);

    //Enable swashbuckle
    SwaggerConfig.Register(HttpConfiguration);

    // Webapi middleware. Do it at the end.
    app.UseWebApi(HttpConfiguration);

    // Register callback to dispose container.
    RegisterShutdownCallback(app, container);
}

public class SwaggerConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableSwagger(c =>
        {
            c.RootUrl(rurl => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["hostUrl"].ToString());
            c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsFileLocation());
            c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Isone");
        })
        .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
        {
        });
    }

    private static string GetXmlCommentsFileLocation()
    {
        var baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\bin";
        var commentsFileName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ".XML";
        var commentsFileLocation = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, commentsFileName);

        return commentsFileLocation;
    }
}
```

Please point out the mistake if any in the code.

Answer (score 6):

The steps should be as follows:

**1)** Add "Swashbuckle.Core" as a NuGet dependency (only the core package is required with OWIN)

package.json

```
<packages>     
    <package id="Swashbuckle.Core" version="5.5.3" targetFramework="net462" />
    ...
</packages>
```

**2)** Within you startup class register swagger

Startup.cs

```
public partial class Startup
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Used to create an instance of the Web application
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app">Parameter supplied by OWIN implementation which our configuration is connected to</param>
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Wire-in the authentication middleware
        ConfigureAuth(app);

        // In OWIN you create your own HttpConfiguration rather than re-using the GlobalConfiguration.
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        // Handle registration of Swagger API docs
        SwaggerConfig.Register(config);

        // Handles registration of the Web API's routes
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);

        // Register web api
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

SwaggerConfig.cs

```
public class SwaggerConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
            {
                c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath());
            })
            .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
            {
                c.EnableApiKeySupport("Authorization", "header");
            });
    }

    private static string GetXmlCommentsPath()
    {
        return $@"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\bin\Example.XML";
    }
}
```

**3)** Enable XML documentation output in your build properties

[image: Build Properties]

**4)** Swagger UI will be served at swagger/ui/index

[image]

Comment: Complementing this answer for programmers that use Visual Studio Code (or other editors), to enable the XML documentation generation on project build, just add to a property group to the csproj with the following line inside it:  ```<GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>```